# Numerical Integration - Maximum degree the approximation may be exact

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I wish to find the maximum degree for which the following approximation may be exact:

$\int_{0}^{2} xf(x)dx \approx A_{0}f(0) + A_{1}f(1) + A_{2}f(2)$

Of course we should find the values of the weights, but I believe that we may immediately say that the approximation is exact for polynomials of degree at most $n=2$.

The RHS of the above equation is essentially the expanded form of the interpolating polynomial $p(x)$ for the function $xf(x)$. That is, $\int_a^b \omega(x)f(x) \approx \int_a^b p(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{n}A_i f(x) $ where $A_i = \int_a^b l_{i}(x)\omega(x)dx$.

To obtain the RHS of our approximation, we must have that $n=2$. Since the interpolating polynomial $p(x)$ has degree at most $2$, then our approximation can be exact for polynomials of degree at most $2$.

**Q.** What is wrong with my logic? By my logic, the approximation in the first problem found here: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~yanovsky/Teaching/Math151A/hw6/Hw6_solutions.pdf should be exact for polynomials of degree at most $n=1$.

Comment: Apply it to the third degree polynomial $f(x)=x(x-1)(x-2)$ to find  that the left side is different from zero while the right is zero independent of the coefficients.

Comment: @LutzL So this means the approximation will be exact for degree at most $2$ yes? Also, how did you know to apply such a polynomial? I plugged in the monomials $1,x,x^2,x^3$ to get a system of equations, but I didn't know what to say about the system

Comment: It is a standard trick to use a polynomial that has roots in the sample points. Note that it does not work if the sample points are not equally spaced. Then you get certainly a contradiction at degree 5 for $x(x-1)^2(x-2)^2$ as the integrand is non-negative non-zero. See Gauß-integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us denote ${\frak E_n}=\{f| f \ \text{is a polynomial with deg(f)} \ \leq n\}.$

The property "there exist "universal constants" $A_0,A_1,A_2$ such that, for any polynomial $f(x) \in {\frak E_n}$:

$$\tag{0}\int_{0}^{2} xf(x)dx = A_{0}f(0) + A_{1}f(1) + A_{2}f(2)$$

has to be examined in two separate cases:

- if $n=2$, the LHS of (0) $\int_0^2 x(ax^2+bx+c)dx=4a+\dfrac{8}{3}b+2c$

has to be identified with its RHS: $A_{0}c + A_{1}(a+b+c) + A_{2}(4a+2b+c)$.

An easy computation show that it is possible with (i.e., there exists a solution) $A_0=0, A_1=4/3, A_2=2/3$.

- if $n > 2$, taking successively $f(x)=x,x^2,x^3$ identifying the LHS and RHS of (0) yields the system of equations:

$$\begin{cases}A_1+2A_2=2 \\ A_1+4A_2=4 \\A_1+8A_2=\dfrac{32}{5} \\ \end{cases}$$

which are non-compatible, thus with no solutions.

---

**Here is a more abstract approach to your issue.**

In fact, formula (0) can be written in the following way:

$$\tag{1}\exists A_0,A_1,A_2 \ \text{such that} \  \forall f \ \ I(f)=A_0 ev_0(f)+A_1 ev_1(f)+A_2 ev_2(f)$$

where $I$ is defined by $I:f \mapsto \int_0^2 x f(x)dx$ and the "evaluation functions" $ev_k$ are defined by $ev_k:f \mapsto f(k)$.

(1), that can be expressed in the abstract form:

$$\tag{2} \exists A_0,A_1,A_2 \ \ \text{such that} \ \  I=A_0 ev_0+A_1 ev_1+A_2 ev_2$$

In which space is (2) meaningful ? Let us fix $n$.

${\frak E_n}$ has been introduced before, with $dim({\frak E_n})=n+1.$

$I$ and the $ev_k$, being linear applications from $\frak{E_n}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ are elements of the dual space $\frak{E_n}^*$ which has the same dimension as   ${\frak E_n}$ : $dim({\frak E_n}^*)=n+1$. Thus, relationship (2) is to be understood in this dual space: it expresses that $I$ belongs to the 3 dimensional subspace generated by $ev_0,ev_1,ev_2$ (because they are independant). It is clear that if $n>2$, $dim({\frak E_n}^*)=n+1>3$, one can say in an intuitive way that there is no reason for $I$ to be in this subspace (this is not a proof ; a proof has already been given!...)

Comment: Jean, thank you for your detailed Answer! I have a question. In my attempt I take successively $f(x) = 1,x,x^2,x^3$ to obtain a system of equations. Why didn't you take the constant polynomial in your successions? ALSO: I'm bad at linear algebra so can you tell me why the system has no solutions?

Comment: Answer to question 1): of course, we can take polynomial 1, but it is not nessery for obtaining rather rapidly a contradiction. Answer to question 2) : substract equ. 1 from equ. 2, you get $A_2=2$, then substract equ. to equ. 3, then we get $A_2=3/5$. Thus we have proved that $2=3/5$...

Comment: Ah yes :) Okay, thank you. I think my next linear algebra question is not meant for a comment on your Answer post. Thanks again!